# Remote management API for Mosquitto MQTT broker

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I would like to manage Mosquitto users from a remote web site. Is there an API or SDK to manage a Mosquitto broker?

Answer (score 0):

**Mosquitto Dynamic Security Plugin** (dynsec) is a plugin providing a MQTT interface for managing clients, groups and roles.

For more info: https://mosquitto.org/documentation/dynamic-security/